# How to encode a string when it is a pb_callback_t type

Tags: c, protocol-buffers, nanopb

I'm working with Nanopb, where the string variable from the generated proto file, is converted to pb_callback_t

So, far I'm trying with a test example of callbacks from nanopb;

```
bool encode_string(pb_ostream_t* stream, const pb_field_t* field, void* const* arg)
{
    char str[14] = "Hello world!";

    if (!pb_encode_tag_for_field(stream, field))
        return false;

    return pb_encode_string(stream, (uint8_t*)str, strlen(str));
}
```

```
int main()
{
FeatureFile featurefile = FeatureFile_init_zero;
pb_ostream_t stream = pb_ostream_from_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

featurefile.features.Id.funcs.encode = &encode_string;
}
```

But with this example, the string "Hello world!" is pretty hardcoded xD, how can I instead pass a string dynamicly to that function, from main?

Comment: What is the `arg` argument for? How can you set that? Is that set for you by the library when the function is called? Can the `main` function set this pointer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `pb_callback_t` struct contains a `void* arg` field which you can use to pass any custom data to the encode/decode function through the `arg` parameter.

In this case you could do:

```
int main()
{
    ... 
    featurefile.features.Id.arg = "something";
    featurefile.features.Id.funcs.encode = &encode_string;
}
```

And note that the `arg` parameter is a *pointer* to `void * const`, so you will always have to dereference it:

```
bool encode_string(pb_ostream_t* stream, const pb_field_t* field, void* const* arg)
{
    const char* str = (const char*)(*arg);

    if (!pb_encode_tag_for_field(stream, field))
        return false;

    return pb_encode_string(stream, (uint8_t*)str, strlen(str));
}
```

Note that you can pass a pointer to any struct, i.e. you can easily create a sort of a "parsing context" struct and pass it around so that you don't need to care how the parsing func will use it.

In this case, it could be something like:

```
typedef struct
{
    const char * something;
    const char * whatever;
    ...
}
callback_context_t;

int main()
{
    callback_context_t ctx = { .something = "something" };

    // this way you always pass the same pointer type
    featurefile.features.Id.arg = &ctx;
    featurefile.features.Id.funcs.encode = &encode_string;
}

bool encode_string(pb_ostream_t* stream, const pb_field_t* field, void* const* arg)
{
    // ...and you always cast to the same pointer type, reducing
    // the chance of mistakes
    callback_context_t * ctx = (callback_context_t *)(*arg);

    if (!pb_encode_tag_for_field(stream, field))
        return false;

    return pb_encode_string(stream, (uint8_t*)ctx->something, strlen(ctx->something));
}
```