# enncoding and decoding issue in nanopb

Tags: protocol-buffers, nanopb

Recently started exploring nanopb - apology if my questions sound sily. I faced some issues while assigning and retrieval of strings and integers when I modified simple example of nanopb. Let me give my steps before my questions -

1. I defined simple.proto file

```
message Device{
optional string devid =1; 
optional string mac = 2; 
optional string cpu=3 [default = "x86"] ; 
optional bool isSecured=4;
optional int32 uptime = 5 [default = 1234];
}
```

2. Also defined simple.option

```
Device.devid max_size:64
Device.cpu max_size:64
```

Then I compiled as usual :  protoc -osimple.pb simple.proto

3. Here is my code  :

3a) Using same string encode decode utility function as in  [How to encode a string when it is a pb_callback_t type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57569586/how-to-encode-a-string-when-it-is-a-pb-callback-t-type)

```
//string encode decode to pb
bool encode_string(pb_ostream_t* stream, const pb_field_t* field, void* const* arg)
{
    const char* str = (const char*)(*arg);

    if (!pb_encode_tag_for_field(stream, field))
        return false;

    return pb_encode_string(stream, (uint8_t*)str, strlen(str));
}

bool print_string(pb_istream_t *stream, const pb_field_t *field, void **arg)
{
    uint8_t buffer[1024] = {0};

    /* We could read block-by-block to avoid the large buffer... */
    if (stream->bytes_left > sizeof(buffer) - 1)
        return false;

    if (!pb_read(stream, buffer, stream->bytes_left))
        return false;

    /* Print the string, in format comparable with protoc --decode.
     * Format comes from the arg defined in main().     */
    printf((char*)*arg, buffer);
    return true;
}
```

3b) here is my main code snippet based on simple.c of example -

```
    /* This is the buffer where we will store our message. */
    uint8_t buffer[128];
    size_t message_length;
    bool status;

    /* Encode our message */
    {
        /* Allocate space on the stack to store the message data, check out the contents of simple.pb.h
         * good to always initialize your structures so that no garbage data from RAM in there.   */

        //Device message = Device_init_zero;   //init zero   for empty
        Device message = Device_init_default;  //init default for default

        /* Create a stream that will write to our buffer. */
        pb_ostream_t stream = pb_ostream_from_buffer(buffer, sizeof(buffer));

        /* Fill in the data */
        message.devid.arg = "device1";
        message.devid.funcs.encode = &encode_string;


        //strcpy(message.devid,"device1");  // no easier way like this ?

        message.isSecured = true;   // should be 1 if printed with %d
        message.uptime=9876;        // should change, why it is not working ?

        /* Now we are ready to encode the message! */
        // encode stream to buffer , also get the buffer length
        status = pb_encode(&stream, Device_fields, &message);
        message_length = stream.bytes_written;

        /* Then just check for any errors.. */
        if (!status)
        {
            printf("Encoding failed: %s\n", PB_GET_ERROR(&stream));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* Now we could transmit the message over network, store it in a file etc.   */
    /* just decode it immediately. */
    {
         /* Allocate space for the decoded message. */
        Device message = Device_init_zero;

        /* Create a stream that reads from the buffer. */
        pb_istream_t stream = pb_istream_from_buffer(buffer, message_length);

        message.devid.funcs.decode = &print_string;
        message.devid.arg = "before decode Device - devid: %s \n"; //works here

        message.cpu.funcs.decode = &print_string;
        message.cpu.arg = "before decode Device -cpu: %s \n";   //where in op?

        printf("before decode isSecured %d\n",message.isSecured);  // doesn't work
        
        printf("before decode uptime %d\n",message.uptime); //doesn't work

        /* Now ready to decode the message. */
        // decode  stream buffer into message
        status = pb_decode(&stream, Device_fields, &message);

        /* Check for errors... */
        if (!status)
        {
            printf("Decoding failed: %s\n", PB_GET_ERROR(&stream));
            return 1;
        }

        /* Print the data contained in the message. */
        
        message.devid.funcs.decode = &print_string;
        message.devid.arg = "after decode Devic - devid: %s \n";  // doesn't work here

        printf(" after decode isSecured %d\n",message.isSecured);  // prints default 0        

    printf(" after decode uptime %d\n",(int)message.uptime);   //prints default assigned in proto
    }
```

4. The output after build and run :

```
$ ./simple
before decode isSecured 0
before decode uptime 0
before decode Device - devid: device1
 after decode isSecured 0
 after decode uptime 1234
```

My queries ( also added my inline comments in code) :

1. In original simple.c message.lucky_number=13 assignment works but here message.uptime assignment is not working , it is taking default value. Similarly assigning boolean value to message.isSecured is not working. Please tell where is my fault.
2. I used Device_init_default before pb_encode  as some have default values and Device_init_zero before pb_decode  call as it will populate after decode. Is my approach correct ?
3. Is there any simpler way to assign string value using strcpy and printing it in C way by printf("%s",strvar)  apart from the encode_string and decode_string util ?
4. The string is printed only before pb_decode call but uptime default value is printed after pb_decode call. Also boolean value assignment is not working. Why ? What is my mistake ?
5. I saw encode string and int functions in https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/blob/master/tests/callbacks/encode_callbacks.c
   How to encode and decode float and boolean ?

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 1):

> 1. In original simple.c message.lucky_number=13 assignment works but here message.uptime assignment is not working , it is taking default value. Similarly assigning boolean value to message.isSecured is not working. Please tell where is my fault.

If you look into the generated `.pb.h` file, you'll find that every optional field has a boolean `has_field`. You'll have to set that to true also, to signify that the field is present.

> 2. I used Device_init_default before pb_encode as some have default values and Device_init_zero before pb_decode call as it will populate after decode. Is my approach correct ?

That's fine.

> 3. Is there any simpler way to assign string value using strcpy and printing it in C way by printf("%s",strvar) apart from the encode_string and decode_string util ?

Because you have already set a `max_size` for your string fields, they should be generated as a `char` array instead of callbacks. You can try passing `-v` switch like: `../generator/nanopb_generator.py -v simple.pb` to see more verbose messages that can point out why the option is not applying. Perhaps the file name is incorrect or the message name is incorrect.

> The string is printed only before pb_decode call but uptime default value is printed after pb_decode call. Also boolean value assignment is not working. Why ? What is my mistake ?

> I saw encode string and int functions in https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/blob/master/tests/callbacks/encode_callbacks.c How to encode and decode float and boolean ?

Well, usually you wouldn't have to resort to callbacks. But if you decide you need them, you can encode booleans with `pb_encode_varint()` and floats with `pb_encode_fixed32()`. For studying callbacks, the [protobuf encoding documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding) and [this test case](https://github.com/nanopb/nanopb/tree/master/tests/alltypes_callback) can be helpful.

---

You may find the `network_server` example useful to study.

Also, the Stack Overflow format works best when you have only a single question per post. That way the questions and answers remain focused and easy to follow.

Comment: Thanks.Setting has_field to true makes assignment work. Also recompiling proto made char array instead of pb_callback struct so could use strcpy.